# How to call an ASP.NET endpoint locally but from another device on the same network? The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, localhost, certificate, liveserver

I have an ASP.NET API running locally. On the MacBook Pro, I can access the endpoints with Swagger, Postman and in the frontend (running on LiveServer) using Axios/JavaScript.

I have successfully loaded the frontend webpage on an iPhone (192.168.0.10:5500/index.html), however the Axios call to the endpoint is failing with the following error message logged to the console `Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.10”, which could put your confidential information at risk.`

Running the command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` generates the message `Successfully trusted the existing HTTPS certificate.` but does not resolve the issue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you trust the cert, you're telling that particular machine to trust the cert. That doesn't mean your iPhone is going to automatically trust it. I've never used Axios, but I imagine you'll need to get it to ignore invalid certs for testing purposes, or use a cert signed by a CA that the iPhone trusts.

Comment: Simply disable HTTP to HTTPS redirection so that your iPhone can use HTTP to access your web app. Or trust that self-signed certificate on iPhone as you are on a development box. Unless you are working for an enterprise, it will be challenging to get a valid certificate that iPhone trusts by default.

Answer (score 0):

@Lex Li's comment worked.

**Steps**

- Remove or comment out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in program.cs file.
- In the launchSettings.json file, `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7139;http://localhost:5171",` generates a http and https url for the API endpoints. Edit the http route to the IP of the computer/local server, e.g., `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7139;http://192.168.0.10:5171"`
- use the http endpoint